# elasticsearch update fields for documents with matching _id

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, python-3.6

Here's how a typical document looks like in my ES database:

```
{
  "_index": "test_index",
  "_type": "data_pt",
  "_id": "AWAEXNYdkjIRDAUZyu8d",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "state": "state_a",
    ...
  }
}
```

In my code, I have already searched with a query, and have stored a list of `_id` for them:

```
query = { 
          ... 
          {
            'term': 'state_a'
          },
          ...
        }
results = es.search(index='test_index',_source=True,body=query)
hits = results['hits']['hits']
queried_id_list = [doc['_id'] for doc in hits]
```

I'm trying to update `state` field of each documents with the matching `_id` from `'state_a'` to `'state_b'`:

```
for _id in queried_id_list:    
    es.update(index='test_index',id='_id,doc_type='data_pt',
              body=update_query)
```

However, this adds a ridiculous amount of overhead, since it's calling `update()` for every single document.

If I try to put `queried_id_list` directly:

```
>>> es.update(index=test_index', id=queried_id_list, doc_type='data_pt', body=update_query)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 526, in update
    raise ValueError("Empty value passed for a required argument.")
ValueError: Empty value passed for a required argument.
```

How can I call a single `update()` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. For the interest of others who struggles the same issue:

```
update_query = {
            'script': {
                'inline': 'ctx._source.state = "state_b"',
                'lang': 'painless'
            },
            'query': {
                'terms': {
                    '_id': queried_id_list
                }
            }
        }
es.update_by_query(index='test_index', doc_type='data_pt', body=update_query)
```